# Is there any connections between boundary points and nowhere dense sets?

Tags: general-topology

Boundary points are defined to be the closure of a set excluding its interior points. A nowhere dense set is when the interior of the closure is empty, so it feels like there should be a theorem liking these two sets. Is that the case?

Comment: Pretty much by definition a nowhere dense set has only boundary points and being nowhere dense is the same as saying that the closure has only boundary points, not sure what else you're expecting

Comment: ok that makes sense

Comment: The boundary of a set could not be nowhere dense right @BrianM.Scott? E.g. the boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: i mean nowhere dense sets are those where the interior of closure is empty. Will edit that

Comment: @saulillo: Oops! I see that I left out a word: that was supposed to be the boundary of any **open** set.

Answer (score 3):

The boundary of an open set and the boundary of a closed set are both always garantueed to be nowhere dense. If a set is nowhere dense, so is its boundary.

But the boundary of an arbitary set can be large (e.g. $\Bbb Q$ in the reals).